# React.js style mutation error......?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is what I'm working with:
react: 15.6.1

The error happens when onChange is triggered.

### Component File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var defaults = {
    text: {
        placeholder: '',
        label: ''
    },
    style: {
        wrapper: {
            display: 'block',
            padding: '9px 0'
        },
        label: {
            display: 'block',
            padding: '0px 8px 4px',
            color: require('macros').theme.text.info
        },
        input: {
            display: 'block',
            position: 'relative',

            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            border: 0,
            outline: 0,
            // border: `1px solid ${ require('macros').theme['text field'].border }`,
            width: '100%',
            padding: '12px 6px',

            fontSize: '16px',

            background: require('macros').theme['text field'].background,
            color: require('macros').theme.text.info
        },
        active: {
            input: require('macros').theme['text field'].active.background
        }
    },
    type: 'text',
    onChange: function() {}
};

export default class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        var component = this;

        component.state = require('venatici').object.combine(defaults, component.props);
        component.onChange = component.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(event) {
        var component = this;
        component.state.onChange(event.target.value);

        component.state.style.input.background = '#494949';
        component.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        var component = this;

        return (
            <text-field
                ref='outer'
                style={ component.state.style.wrapper }
            >
                <label style={ component.state.style.label }>{ component.state.text.label }</label>
                <input
                    name={ component.state.type }
                    type={ component.state.type }
                    style={ component.state.style.input }
                    placeholder={ component.state.text.placeholder }
                    onChange={ component.onChange }
                ></input>
            </text-field>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }
}
```

### Error

Warning: `input` was passed a style object that has previously been mutated. Mutating `style` is deprecated. Consider cloning it beforehand. Check the `render` of `Nav`. Previous style: {display: "block", position: "relative", boxSizing: "border-box", border: 0, outline: 0, width: "100%", padding: "12px 6px", fontSize: "16px", background: "#333", color: "#eee"}. Mutated style: {display: "block", position: "relative", boxSizing: "border-box", border: 0, outline: 0, width: "100%", padding: "12px 6px", fontSize: "16px", background: "#494949", color: "#eee"}.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: DO NOT mutate state directly. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
component.state.style.input.background = '#494949';
component.forceUpdate();
```

do

```
const inputStyles = Object.assign({}, component.state.style.input, { background: '#494949' });
const styles = Object.assign({}, component.state.style, { input: inputStyles });
component.setState({ style: styles });
```

Comment: Seems like this computation could get heavy for complex states... though it seems like this is the only way... (if only there were component.assignState( ) as well)...

Comment: as @gravityplanx pointed out, this would be a lot easier if your component state wasn't so deeply nested. Furthermore, state should really only hold values that change over the course of the app. I'm not sure how the venatici package works, but is it necessary to keep it in state? If not, you could easily have state only hold the input's background color.

Answer (score 2):

```
    component.state.style.input.background = '#494949';
    component.forceUpdate();
```

This section is very incorrect.

First of all, you should never change any value in the state of your component directly.  The one and only way you are allowed to change the state is by using the `setState` hook.

Second, `forceUpdate` is a hook for extreme edge cases.  In general, if you find you need to use it, it means there is a serious problem in your code.  In this case, that is because you are not using `setState` when you should.  `setState` will always cause the component to re-evaluate it's render method and determine whether or not it needs to update.

Lastly, while not "wrong", there's no reason to use the assignment `component = this`.  If you're in a context where the `this` keyword is no longer the component then, again, that indicates a problem with your code structure.

You could replace those two lines with the following;

```
this.setState((oldState) => { 
    return {
        ...oldState, 
        style: { 
            ...oldState.style, 
            input: {
                ...oldState.style.input,
                background: '#494949'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This could be a lot cleaner if you didn't use such deeply nested state models, but it's still very functional this way.

Comment: Yep.  That's why it's advised not to use deeply nested states.  If you had `inputStyle` as a top level object on the state, it would instead simply be `return { inputStyle: {...oldState.inputStyle, background: '#494949' } };`